# Use of two same words repeating immediately

Tags: grammar, syntax, construction, semantics, morphology

**Button, Button** is the title of a short story by Richard Mathewson. The title has the same word two times. Is it the use epizeuxis to lay stress like `Papa, Papa I want to go to picnic`? If not, how will we define it in terms of grammar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think the use of a double word in a title usually emphaises and stresses on the word "button" in this case. So this should be epizeuxis as you have mentioned.